# Nestjs typeorm querybuilder with select not returning relations field but when .select() is removed it returns relations

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

when I try to query invoices with query builder .select() it does not return the selected field in the relation but If I remove the .select() it returns all the relations,

My question is how do I make the .select([...required fields]) works is there something wrong in my invoice relations table that is causing this issue

```
  async clientInvoices(currentUser: User, invoiceQueryDto: InvoiceQueryDto) {
    try {
      const { limit, page } = invoiceQueryDto;

      const invoices = await this.invoiceRepo
        .createQueryBuilder('i')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('i.proposal', 'p')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('p.service_request', 'sr')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('sr.created_by', 'client')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('p.service_provider', 'sp')
        .where('client.id = :id', { id: currentUser.id })
        .select([
          'i.id',
          'i.ref',
          'i.client_service_fee',
          'i.client_payable_amount',
          'i.date_paid',
          'i.invoice_sent_date',
          'i.invoice_accept_date',
          'i.invoice_cancel_date',
          'i.status',
          'i.discount_code',

          // service request
          'sr.id',
          'sr.start_add',
          'sr.start_add',
          'sr.start_state',
          'sr.start_city',

          // service provider
          'sp.id',
          'sp.first_name',
          'sp.last_name',
        ])
        .getMany();
      console.log(invoices);
      return await paginateArray<Invoice>(invoices, limit, page);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new CatchErrorException(error);
    }
  }
```

Here is the invoice repo

```
@Entity()
export class Invoice extends SharedEntity {
  @Column()
  ref: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  sp_service_fee: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  client_service_fee: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  amount: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  client_payable_amount: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  sp_receivable_amount: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  system_receivable_amount: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  date_paid: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  invoice_sent_date: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  invoice_accept_date: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  invoice_cancel_date: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'float' })
  cancel_service_fee_percent: number;

  @Column({ type: 'float' })
  cancel_service_fee_system_share_percent: number;

  @Column({ type: 'float' })
  cancel_service_fee_sp_share_percent: number;

  @OneToOne(() => Proposal, (proposal) => proposal.invoice)
  @JoinColumn()
  proposal: Proposal;

  @Column()
  proposal_id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: InvoiceStatus })
  status: InvoiceStatus;

  @OneToOne(() => DiscountCode)
  @JoinColumn()
  discount_code: DiscountCode;
}
```